# Different Versions of Haneirot Hallalu

Tags: tefilla, chanuka, nuschaot, menora-chanukia

My father ususally lights the hannuka candles and reads the blessings from the Authorized Daily Prayer Book (aka the Singer Siddur). This year he is away and I read the blessings from the Artscroll. I was baffled by the tune of Haneirot Hallalu because the siddur had more words than could fit in the tune that I knew. Tonight (the last night), I put the two siddurs side by side and noticed that the artscroll references Milhamot but the Singer does not.

Wence the difference in litturgy?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/50622

Comment: That question is a duplicate of mine!

Comment: @ClintEastwood Yours doesn't have an answer, so there's no option for a user to select it to close the other one as a duplicate.